# How does the impementation for std::is_function in libcxx work?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, libc++

In `libcxx/include/type_traits`, `std::is_function` is implemented in such a compact way:

```cpp
namespace __libcpp_is_function_imp
{
struct __dummy_type {};
template <class _Tp> char  __test(_Tp*);
template <class _Tp> char __test(__dummy_type);
template <class _Tp> __two __test(...);
template <class _Tp> _Tp&  __source(int);
template <class _Tp> __dummy_type __source(...);
}

template <class _Tp, bool = is_class<_Tp>::value ||
                            is_union<_Tp>::value ||
                            is_void<_Tp>::value  ||
                            is_reference<_Tp>::value ||
                            __is_nullptr_t<_Tp>::value >
struct __libcpp_is_function
    : public integral_constant<bool,
                               sizeof(__libcpp_is_function_imp::__test<_Tp>(
                                      __libcpp_is_function_imp::__source<_Tp>(0))) == 1>
    {};
template <class _Tp> struct __libcpp_is_function<_Tp, true> : public false_type {};

template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_function
    : public __libcpp_is_function<_Tp> {};
```

I got the general idea. **If a type does not match any of the non-function type (class, union, void, reference, nullptr_t), it is a function type.**.  However, I can't find the meaning for this line:

```cpp
sizeof(__libcpp_is_function_imp::__test<_Tp>(__libcpp_is_function_imp::__source<_Tp>(0))) == 1
```

I think, the result type for `__libcpp_is_function_imp::__source<_Tp>(0)` should be `_Tp&`. So the result type for `__libcpp_is_function_imp::__test<_Tp>(_Tp&)` should be `_two`. And `sizeof(_two)` should equal to 2, which is different from `1`. In other words, the equation `sizeof(__libcpp_is_function_imp::__test<_Tp>(__libcpp_is_function_imp::__source<_Tp>(0))) == 1` is always false.

But I must get something wrong. Could anyone point me out?

Comment: Unless I'm blind, the line with the `sizeof` has 3 opening `<`'s but only two closing `>`'s...

Comment: Sorry for my typo. Thanks for your comment. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Where did you find that definition? I see [something else](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/type_traits#L889) in libc++ source code. It basically uses a clang `__is_function` intrinsics.

Comment: Note that they later came up with an even more clever implementation (see [patch](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/commit/871b040ee3c38f0168600e880c696e5eb8479d9d#diff-48f5ee43879b5ad38888f0a6ead10113)). The idea is that reference and function types are the only types such that an attempt to add cv-qualification is ignored.

Comment: @DanielLangr I find this definition in https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/release/9.x/libcxx/include/type_traits, which is in `release/9.x` branch.

Comment: @Brian Wow, the new implementation is really cool. And I learned more about type casts in cpp. There are so many rules to be known.

Comment: Hey, could someone help me understand how the basic part works?
We have two implementation of __libcpp_is_function: 
(1) template <class _Tp, bool = ... > struct __libcpp_is_function
(2) template <class _Tp> struct __libcpp_is_function<_Tp, true>
For me, it seems that second one is more specialized. And it is used as __libcpp_is_function<_Tp>. So it seems the second candidate is always chosen.
Which part of my analysis is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every type in C++ falls into exactly one of the following categories, possibly cv-qualified:

- `void`
- `decltype(nullptr)` (a.k.a. `std::nullptr_t`)
- Arithmetic
- Array
- Pointer (*i.e.*, `T*` for some type `T`)
- Reference (lvalue or rvalue)
- Pointer to non-static member
- Enumeration
- `class` or `struct`
- `union`
- Function

After eliminating `class`, `union`, `void`, reference, and `std::nullptr_t` we are left with the following possible types:

- Arithmetic
- Array
- Pointer
- Pointer to non-static member
- Enumeration
- Function

The remaining template metaprogramming exploits two facts about the types in these remaining categories:

- If `_Tp` is an [abominable function type](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html), then the attempt to create the reference type `_Tp&` is ill-formed. Otherwise, `_Tp&` is well-formed.
- Otherwise, the type `_Tp` is convertible to `_Tp*` if and only if `_Tp` is a function type, via the function-to-pointer conversion.

It's left as an exercise for the reader to determine why `class`, `union`, `void`, reference, and `std::nullptr_t` types had to be eliminated at an earlier stage before this test would work correctly.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for your great and clear answer. So the key point is that if `_Tp` is a function type, i.e., `void (*)()`, then it is convertible to `(void (*)())*`. This is a little counter-intuitive. Is there any convincing explanation? Or this is just a rule?

Comment: @yodahaji No, `void()` can be converted to `void(*)()`. `void(*)()` is already a pointer type, so it can't be converted to a double pointer type `void(**)()`. The function-to-pointer conversion originated in C.

Comment: OK, I got it. Thx for your answer.